# ¿Se pueden hacer inserciones con llaves foraneas en una misma transaccion?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, transacciones

Tengo dos tablas, un campo de ellas hace referencia al campo de la otra.

```sql
CREATE TABLE primaryExample (
    field VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE secondaryExample (
    field VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
    foreign_field VARCHAR(30) REFERENCES primaryExample(field)
);
```

Y tengo una transaccion que ejecuto en Go (Golang), que primero inserta un registro en primaryExample y luego secondaryExample.
El problema es que al realizar la transaccion, me da el siguiente error:

```sql
 pq: insert or update on table "secondaryExample" violates foreign key constraint "secondaryExample_foreign_field_fkey"
```

Yo pienso que es porque la insercion del primer registro, aun no se ha realizado debido a que la transaccion aun no termina, por lo que el segundo registro, que hace referencia al otro, da error.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Habría que revisar tu código, tal vez pasaste algo por alto...

Comment: "Yo pienso que es porque la insercion del primer registro, aun no se ha realizado debido a que la transaccion aun no termina", te confirmo que no es así, lo que ocurre dentro de una transacción es "visible" dentro de la transacción, si no no tendría sentido transaccionar. El problema es que seguramente no estás insertando el valor adecuado. Por otro lado, revisa también el mensaje de error que publicaste por que parece incompleto. Saludos.

Comment: Estas trabajando con gorm ? , algun ORM ? o sql puro, el problema que tienes es que al intentar insertar secondaryExample debes indicarle el valor field que ingresaste en primaryExample, revisa que las dos operaciones esten en el mismo contexto ya que los cambios realizados en contextos diferentes no se pueden ver entre si